# Google Drive Not Syncing Folder Correctly

Tags: microsoft-excel, sync, google-drive

I have a bit of a strange issue with my 'Backup and Sync' Google Drive. Specifically only 1 file in a particular folder I have selected to sync is not syncing to my device and I cant figure out why. More details below.

I have configured my Google Drive as follows:

[image: Drive Config]

However if I view the following file path

google_drive_location\VBA_CODE_ENVIRONMENT_STAND_ALONE\PACKAGES\REPO_CREATE_MANIFOLD_DWGS

On the web portal for Google Drive the following appears...

[image: Excel File on Google Drive]

But when I view it on my local computer the excel file shown is nowhere to be seen!

[image: Excel File not on Device]

I have tried the following to fix the issue:

- Ensure Google Drive has finished syncing
- Uninstall and re-install Google Drive (twice!)

Does anyone on here have any ideas why this file is not syncing??

Comment: Did you set up a filter somewhere, that would prevent Google Drive to download .xlsm files?

Comment: You can setup filters?

Comment: I'm not sure, as I don't use Google Drive myself, but this is a feature that exists on some other cloud services. I thought this file type might be unchecked for some reason.

Comment: @piko I just checked and excluding file types is not supported by Google Drive. https://www.quora.com/Google-Drive-Can-I-exclude-files-from-sync-based-on-filename-extension Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Google's advice specifically for their failure to sync Excel files is to not use Excel. That's right, this terrible technical problem can only be solved by using Google Sheets, according to Google. No explanation as to why, out of all file types, specifically Excel files can't be sync'd.

https://support.google.com/docs/forum/AAAABuH1jm0JIKWSl8UZZA/?hl=en&gpf=d/topic/docs/JIKWSl8UZZA

So there's the official answer: Use Google Sheets. I sympathize if you suspect there is more than technical difficulties involved.

Answer (score 0):

Saving the file as .xls (Save As -> Excel 1997-2003 Workbook) worked for me and allowed sync.